# How to write single query with TOPNSKIP, DATESBETWEEN, and FILTERS in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Execute following DAX functions in single query.

- TOPNSKIP
- DATESBETWEEN
- FILTER/FILTERS

where I can do a query with TOPNSKIP with FILTER/FILTERS, it worked and returns data

```
EVALUATE TOPNSKIP
    (10, 10,
            FILTER(Sales,Sales[Name] = "computer")
    ) ORDER BY 'Sales'[PurchasedDate] ASC
```

It return all rows where Name="computer"

But when try following two queries first one is working if **SKIP value 0**

```
EVALUATE TOPNSKIP
    (10, 0, SUMMARIZECOLUMNS
            (
                'Sales'[Name],'Sales'[PurchasedDate],DATESBETWEEN ('Sales'[PurchasedDate], DATE(2022, 01, 01) , DATE(2022, 02, 01)),
                 FILTER(Sales,Sales[Name] = "computer")
            )
    ) ORDER BY 'Sales'[PurchasedDate] DESC
```

It returns data for the 2 columns

When I execute following query if skip=10, query failed to execute

```
EVALUATE TOPNSKIP
    (10, 10, SUMMARIZECOLUMNS
            (
                'Sales'[Name],'Sales'[PurchasedDate],DATESBETWEEN ('Sales'[PurchasedDate], DATE(2022, 01, 01) , DATE(2022, 02, 01)),
                 FILTER(Sales,Sales[Name] = "computer")
            )
    ) ORDER BY 'Sales'[PurchasedDate] DESC
```

Error: `TOPNSKIP is not supported with the given parameter combination. Please review MSDN documentation.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved with following query

```
EVALUATE CALCULATETABLE  
(
        TOPNSKIP( 10, 10, 'Sales', 'Sales'[PurchasedDate], DESC )
        ,FILTER(Sales,Sales[Name] = "Computer")
        ,DATESBETWEEN ('Sales'[PurchasedDate], DATE(2021, 01, 01) , DATE(2022, 01, 31))  
)
```